# 'BertTokenizerFast' object has no attribute 'get_vocab_size'

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model

what might be the alternative for self.num_classes = self.vocab.get_vocab_size("labels")?

```
 AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-30-6e7fa89b8cf6> in <module>()
    ----> 1 model = BertTextClassifier(tokenizer,text_field).to(device) 
          2 #model = AutoModel.from_pretrained('allenai/scibert_scivocab_uncased').to(device)
          3 optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=3e-5)

<ipython-input-26-b461bb60ce9b> in __init__(self, vocab, text_field_embedder, verbose_metrics, dropout, initializer, regularizer)
     33         self.text_field_embedder = text_field_embedder
     34         self.dropout = torch.nn.Dropout(dropout)
---> 35         self.num_classes = self.vocab.get_vocab_size("labels")
    

AttributeError: 'BertTokenizerFast' object has no attribute 'get_vocab_size'
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Why do you think it would have this method? It’s not listed in the documentation.

Comment: I wanted to use the class shared in this link:https://github.com/allenai/scibert/blob/master/scibert/models/bert_text_classifier.py . Which model I should use? I am actually lost in this implementation. I try to make a regression model that predicts the scores of positivity and negativity in scientific articles. any additional recommendation would be great.

Comment: Ok, I see you’ve asked several questions trying to use this package. All of the problems come from the fact that the package versions you’re using are incompatible. You should install scibert, then install its dependencies using `pip install -r requirements.txt` as their documentation shows.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy , What you are saying does not answer my question :( I already installed dependencies... It would be helpful if you tell me which model to use and why this line: self.num_classes = self.vocab.get_vocab_size("labels") gives error?

Comment: You’re using the wrong versions of AllenNLP and the pytorch-transformers package—too recent. Install scibert’s dependencies in a clean environment.